# How to best parallelize parsing of webpages?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am using the html agility pack to parse individual pages of a forum website. So the parsing method returns all the topic/thread links on the page link, passed as an argument. I gather all these topic links of all the parsed pages in a single collection.

After that, I check if they are on my `Dictionary` of already-viewed urls, and if they are not, then I add them to a new list and the UI shows this list, which is basically new topics/threads created since last time.

Since all these operations seem independent, what would be the best way to parallelize this?

Should I use .NET 4.0's `Parallel.For/ForEach`?

Either way, how can I gather the results of each page in a single collection? Or is this not necessary?

Can I read from my centralized `Dictionary` whenever a parse method finishes to see if they are there, simultaneously?

If I run this program for 4000 pages, it takes like 90 mins, it would be great if I could use all my 8 cores to finish the same task in ~10 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that, I check if they are on my Dictionary of already-viewed urls, and if they are not, then I add them to a new list and the UI shows this list, which is basically new topics/threads created since last time.
>   Since all these operations seem independent, what would be the best way to parallelize this?

You can certainly use Parallel.For/ForEach to do that, but you should think about the design of your crawler a bit. Most crawlers tend to dedicate several threads to crawling and each thread is associated with a page fetching client which is responsible for fetching the pages (in your case, probably using the `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`) I would recommend reading these papers:

- [Mercator: A scalable, extensible Web crawler](http://coitweb.uncc.edu/~sakella/courses/cloud09/papers/Mercator.pdf) (an 11 page paper, should be a pretty light read).
- [IRLbot: Scaling to 6 Billion Pages and Beyond](http://irl.cse.tamu.edu/people/hsin-tsang/papers/www2008.pdf) (a 10 page paper that describes a crawler that crawls at about 600 pages per second on a 150 Mbit connection).
- [IRLbot: Scaling to 6 billion pages and beyond: full paper](http://irl.cse.tamu.edu/people/hsin-tsang/papers/tweb2009.pdf)

If you implement the `Mercator` design, then you should easily be able to download 50 pages per second, so you 4000 pages will be downloaded in 80 seconds.

> Either way, how can I gather the results of each page in a single collection?

You can store your results in a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, like Darin mentioned. You don't need to store anything in the value, since your key would be the link/URL, however if you're performing a [URL-seen Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834808/designing-a-web-crawler/5834890#5834890) then you can hash each link/URL into an integer and then store the hash as the key and the link/URL as the value.

> Or is this not necessary?

It's entirely up to you to decide what's necessary, but if you're performing a URL-seen Test, then it is necessary.

> Can I read from my centralized Dictionary whenever a parse method finishes to see if they are there, simultaneously?

Yes, the `ConcurrentDictionary` allows multiple threads to read simultaneously, so it should be fine. It will work fine if you just want to see if a link has already been crawled.

> If I run this program for 4000 pages, it takes like 90 mins, it would be great if I could use all my 8 cores to finish the same task in ~10 mins.

If you design your crawler sufficiently well, you should be able to download and parse (extracts all the links) of 4000 pages in about 57 seconds on an average desktop PC... I get roughly those results with the standard C# `WebRequest` on a 4GB, i5 3.2 GHz PC with a 10 Mbps connection.

Comment: Thanks, the Mercator design might be a little complex for me to implement, but I will collect all the extracted links in a `ConcurrentDictionary`, and then after this is done gather the new links by checking against my centralized collection which I also want to make a `ConcurrentDictionary`, so I can also do this step in parallel. That's the best I could think of.

Answer (score 4):

`Parallel.For/ForEach` combined with a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) to share state between different threads seem like a good way to implement this. The concurrent dictionary ensures safe read/write from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, you mean store all the links from the parsed pages in a ConcurrentDictionary or everytime a method extracts its links, it searches my centralized collection for the new links, where this centralized collection should be a ConcurrentDictionary?