# How to identify web-crawler?

Tags: php, web-crawler

How can I filter out hits from webcrawlers etc. Hits which not is human..

I use maxmind.com to request the city from the IP.. It is not quite cheap if I have to pay for ALL hits including webcrawlers, robots etc.

Comment: Why don't you license the database so you can use it locally without any per-request payments?!

Comment: what about cacheing the result from maxmind.com. In that way, I think the ratio of querys caused by robots/humans will be ok.

Comment: I realize this is a pretty old post. I am also using this service and have found that using AJAX is a pretty sure way of filtering all bots. We initially launched this feature by only using PHP and we almost hit our allocation for the month in a few days. After switching to AJAX it has become responsible. Personally I would use the new HTML 5 GEO location as it is much more accurate but the owner did not like the browser's confirmation prompt.

Comment: I don't think you can actually limit crawling without affecting real users. Good luck with that

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are two general ways to detect robots and I would call them "Polite/Passive" and "Aggressive". Basically, you have to give your web site a psychological disorder.

### Polite

These are ways to politely tell crawlers that they shouldn't crawl your site and to limit how often you are crawled. Politeness is ensured through [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file in which you specify which bots, if any, should be allowed to crawl your website and how often your website can be crawled. This assumes that the robot you're dealing with is polite.

### Aggressive

Another way to keep bots off your site is to get aggressive.

**User Agent**

Some aggressive behavior includes (as previously mentioned by other users) the filtering of user-agent strings. This is probably the simplest, but also the least reliable way to detect if it's a user or not. A lot of bots tend to spoof user agents and some do it for legitimate reasons (i.e. they only want to crawl mobile content), while others simply don't want to be identified as bots. Even worse, some bots spoof legitimate/polite bot agents, such as the user agents of google, microsoft, lycos and other crawlers which are generally considered polite. Relying on the user agent can be helpful, but not by itself.

There are more aggressive ways to deal with robots that spoof user agents AND don't abide by your robots.txt file:

**Bot Trap**

I like to think of this as a "Venus Fly Trap," and it basically punishes any bot that wants to play tricks with you.

A bot trap is probably the most effective way to find bots that don't adhere to your robots.txt file without actually impairing the usability of your website. Creating a bot trap ensures that only bots are captured and not real users. The basic way to do it is to setup a directory which you specifically mark as off limits in your robots.txt file, so any robot that is polite will not fall into the trap. The second thing you do is to place a "hidden" link from your website to the bot trap directory (this ensures that real users will never go there, since real users never click on invisible links). Finally, you ban any IP address that goes to the bot trap directory.

Here are some instructions on how to achieve this:
[Create a bot trap](http://danielwebb.us/software/bot-trap/) (or in your case: a [PHP bot trap](http://www.kloth.net/internet/bottrap.php)).

Note: of course, some bots are smart enough to read your robots.txt file, see all the directories which you've marked as "off limits" and STILL ignore your politeness settings (such as crawl rate and allowed bots). Those bots will probably not fall into your bot trap despite the fact that they are not polite.

**Violent**

I think this is actually too aggressive for the general audience (and general use), so if there are any kids under the age of 18, then please take them to another room!

You can make the bot trap "**violent**" by simply not specifying a robots.txt file. In this situation **ANY BOT** that crawls the hidden links will probably end up in the bot trap and you can ban all bots, period!

The reason this is not recommended is that you may actually want some bots to crawl your website (such as Google, Microsoft or other bots for site indexing). Allowing your website to be politely crawled by the bots from Google, Microsoft, Lycos, etc. will ensure that your site gets indexed and it shows up when people search for it on their favorite search engine.

**Self Destructive**

Yet another way to limits what bots can crawl on your website, is to serve CAPTCHAs or other challenges which a bot cannot solve. This comes at an expense of your users and I would think that anything which makes your website less usable (such as a CAPTCHA) is "self destructive." This, of course, will not actually block the bot from repeatedly trying to crawl your website, it will simply make your website very uninteresting to them. There are ways to "get around" the CAPTCHAs, but they're difficult to implement so I'm not going to delve into this too much.

### Conclusion

For your purposes, probably the best way to deal with bots is to employ a combination of the above mentioned strategies:

1. Filter user agents.
2. Setup a bot trap (the violent one).

Catch all the bots that go into the violent bot trap and simply black-list their IPs (but don't block them). This way you will still get the "benefits" of being crawled by bots, but you will not have to pay to check the IP addresses that are black-listed due to going to your bot trap.

Comment: Note: AFAIK, recaptcha is own by google, so... they are *theoretically* able to easily bypass it.

Comment: Creative! Still very effective!

Comment: I think the venus traps are called "honey pot".

Answer (score 9):

You can check USER_AGENT, something like:

```
function crawlerDetect($USER_AGENT)
{
    $crawlers = array(
    array('Google', 'Google'),
    array('msnbot', 'MSN'),
    array('Rambler', 'Rambler'),
    array('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
    array('AbachoBOT', 'AbachoBOT'),
    array('accoona', 'Accoona'),
    array('AcoiRobot', 'AcoiRobot'),
    array('ASPSeek', 'ASPSeek'),
    array('CrocCrawler', 'CrocCrawler'),
    array('Dumbot', 'Dumbot'),
    array('FAST-WebCrawler', 'FAST-WebCrawler'),
    array('GeonaBot', 'GeonaBot'),
    array('Gigabot', 'Gigabot'),
    array('Lycos', 'Lycos spider'),
    array('MSRBOT', 'MSRBOT'),
    array('Scooter', 'Altavista robot'),
    array('AltaVista', 'Altavista robot'),
    array('IDBot', 'ID-Search Bot'),
    array('eStyle', 'eStyle Bot'),
    array('Scrubby', 'Scrubby robot')
    );

    foreach ($crawlers as $c)
    {
        if (stristr($USER_AGENT, $c[0]))
        {
            return($c[1]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// example

$crawler = crawlerDetect($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Answer (score 8):

The user agent ([`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) often identifies whether the connecting agent is a browser or a robot. Review logs/analytics for the user agents of crawlers that visit your site. Filter accordingly.

Take note that the user agent is a header supplied by the client application. As such it can be pretty much anything and shouldn't be trusted 100%. Plan accordingly.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you should add the disclaimer that user agent checking is only useful for webcrawlers that identify themselves.  It is trivial to spoof user agent strings.

Comment: @jadewards, I second that... a lot of crawlers spoof user agents. Sometimes it's even necessary, because websites deliver different content depending on the user agent (e.g. mobile browsers vs standard browsers).

Comment: You should add a link to an up-to date site, cause that was the main reason for your good answer

Answer (score 5):

Checking the User-Agent will protect you from legitimate bots like Google and Yahoo.

However, if you're also being hit with spam bots, then chances are User-Agent comparison won't protect you since those bots typically forge a common User-Agent string anyway.  In that instance, you would need to imploy more sophisticated measures.  If user input is required, a simple image verification scheme like ReCaptcha will work.

If you're looking to filter out all page hits from a bot, unfortunately, there's no 100% reliable way to do this if the bot is forging its credentials.  This is just an annoying fact of life on the internet that web admins have to put up with.

Answer (score 2):

[useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/) is serving a lilst that you can use to analyze the userstring:

```
$api_request="http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."&getJSON=all";
$ua=json_decode(file_get_contents($api_request), true);
if($ua["agent_type"]=="Crawler") die();
```

Comment: useragentstring.com is no longer online, and this is a fine example as to why you should not rely on a 3rd party.

Comment: useragentstring.com IS online - I just fetched from their API. The link in this answer is just broken (If you want the list of crawlers the link is now: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Crawler).

Comment: You are treating the returned JSON as an associative array but not specifying in json_decode that an associative array should be returned instead of a JSON object. I submitted an edit to your post.

Comment: @Rasmus: can you lṕls edit my anser accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

I found this package, it's actively being developed and I'm quite liking it so far:

https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

It's simple as this:

```
use Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect;

$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;

// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler()) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
}

// Pass a user agent as a string
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler('Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Sosospider/2.0; +http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)')) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
}

// Output the name of the bot that matched (if any)
echo $CrawlerDetect->getMatches();
```