# How to Prevent spiders/search engines from following the 'report as offensive content' link

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a rails application. In my comments section I have report as offensive content' link  on some (article) pages of the site. I want to get crowed the articles  by search engines but not particular link `report as offensive content`.

So , In brief , My question is  - 
How to Prevent spiders/search engines from following the 'report as offensive content' link of my site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one answer

Pros : - Its easy . Just One line

```
<a href="mypage.html" rel="nofollow" />
```

But Cons :-

Our tests show that some search engines do crawl and index nofollow links. The nofollow tag will probably diminish the ranking value a link will provide but it cannot be reliably used to stop search engines from following a link.

Comment: But as per this blog it says nofollow supports many search engines http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing#SEI20

Comment: there are a LOT of things that you can do to identify a web-crawler and prevent it from crawling a specific page. See my answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404775/how-to-identify-web-crawler/8405803#8405803

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what links for web crawlers not to crawl with a `robots.txt` file.

Learn more here:

http://www.robotstxt.org/

Here's an example. Create a `robots.txt` in the most top level directory of your application so it can be accessed by your domain.com/robots.txt.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /offensive
```

This says for every User-Agent, ignore the `/offensive` url.