# Google app engine - Sudden Increase of Datastore Read Operations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm maintaining a blog app([blog.wokanxing.info](http://blog.wokanxing.info), it's in Chinese) for myself which was built upon Google app engine. It's been like two or three years since first deployment and I've never met any quota issue because its simpicity and small visit count.

However since **early last month**, I noticed that from time to time the app reported 500 server error, and in admin panel it shows a mysterious fast consumption of free datatstore read operation quota. **Within a single hour about 10% of free read quota (~5k ops) are consumed**, but I'm counting only a dozen requests that involve datastore read ops, 30 tops, which means an average 150 to 200 read op per request, which sounds impossible to me.

**I've not commited any change to my codebase for months**, and I'm not seeing any change in datastore or quote policy either. Despite that, it also confuses me how such consumption can be made. I use **memcache** a lot, which leaves first page the biggest player, which fetch the first threads using `Post.all.order('-date').fetch(10, offset)`. Other request merely fetch a single model using `Post.get_by_key_name` and iterates `post.comment_set`.

Sorry for my poor English, but can anyone give me some clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Admin console check your log. 
Do not check for errors only, rather check all types of messages inside the log.

Look for the requests made by robots/web crawlers. In most cases, you can detect such "users" by words "robot" or "bot" (well, if they are honest...).
The first thing you can do is to edit your "robot" file. For more detail read  [How to identify web-crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404775/how-to-identify-web-crawler) . Also, GAE has help for use of "robot" file.

If that fails, try to detect IP address used by bot/bots. Using  GAE Admin console put such addresses in blacklist and check your quota consumption again.