# Toggle links for crawler and guest visitors

Tags: php, html, css

I need display two different links for crawler and for guest. Example:
Crawler see normal link - `<a href="example.com">example.com</a>`
Guest see link - `<a href="other.com/register">Register to see link</a>`

```
// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($Detect->isCrawler()) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
}else{
    // false
}
```

Comment: Giving a search engine some juicy content when you'll give an ordinary user a registration page sounds like a good way to get penalised by search engines.

Comment: Can  anyone confirm this advise? Are You sure? Facebook use hiding links.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you can determine if your site is being crawled by looking at the 'User-Agent' header:

```
function isWebCrawler() {
  $isCrawler = false;

  $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  if(strlen(strstr($userAgent, "Google")) <= 0 ) {
    $isCrawler = true;
  }

  return $isCrawler;
}
```

Here is a listing of the User Agent strings for most of the major bots:
[List of Web Crawler User Agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/)

Answer (score 1):

**Blocking with robots.txt**
Unfortunetely there isn't really a fool proof system to detect bots. Using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file, will allow you to block most legitimate bots out there. However, there are a lot of more "aggressive" bots out there that will simply ignore this file. Also, your question is to detect them and not to block them.

**Detect with User Agent**
So the second best way to detect bots, would be to check the user agent using [$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). For example:

```
function isCrawler($agent)
{
    $crawlers = array(
        array('Google', 'Google'),
        array('msnbot', 'MSN'),
        array('Rambler', 'Rambler'),
        array('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
        array('AbachoBOT', 'AbachoBOT'),
        array('accoona', 'Accoona'),
        array('AcoiRobot', 'AcoiRobot'),
        array('ASPSeek', 'ASPSeek'),
        array('CrocCrawler', 'CrocCrawler'),
        array('Dumbot', 'Dumbot'),
        array('FAST-WebCrawler', 'FAST-WebCrawler'),
        array('GeonaBot', 'GeonaBot'),
        array('Gigabot', 'Gigabot'),
        array('Lycos', 'Lycos spider'),
        array('MSRBOT', 'MSRBOT'),
        array('Scooter', 'Altavista robot'),
        array('AltaVista', 'Altavista robot'),
        array('IDBot', 'ID-Search Bot'),
        array('eStyle', 'eStyle Bot'),
        array('Scrubby', 'Scrubby robot')
    );

    foreach ($crawlers as $c)
    {
        if (stristr($agent, $c[0]))
        {
            return($c[1]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$crawler = isCrawler($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

**Using an external resource for more reliability**
However, there's so many bots out there, that your array would become extremely large to catch them all. Not to mention it'll be outdated very fast. Therefor using an external resource that updates a lot is more reliable. The website [UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/) is providing such a service. A simple code like this would do the trick for you:

```
$api_request="http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."&getJSON=all";
$ua=json_decode(file_get_contents($api_request));
if($ua["agent_type"]=="Crawler"){
    echo '<a href="example.com">example.com</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="other.com/register">Register to see link</a>';
}
```

Credits to this question: [How to identify web-crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404775/how-to-identify-web-crawler)